# Google foobar responds with Error(400)

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve Google's [foobar challenges](http://www.google.com/foobar/). I'm not going to spoil the actual question for anyone else, but the title is "Save Beta Rabbit". My solution is coded in Java, and every time I try to verify it I get an `Error(400): Bad request`. This appears to be an error on their part. I've tested the code locally on my machine and it works fine. Also, if it was a problem with runtime or memory, foobar explicitly tells you that. It also explicitly tells you when you have complier errors. Anybody know anything about this? Challenge is on a timer here.

UPDATE: I've traced down where the bug is. When you recursively call the same static method twice, the bug occurs. Unless anyone else has seen this before, I'm going to report it to Google through the feedback mechanism and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error in a Java solution. Without getting into implementation details, it turns out it was a performance problem. After I fixed it the verifier worked.