# google foobar challenge error with dfs solution

Tags: java

I received the invite to attened google code challenge. I got a problem like find the minimun path in the maze while you are allow to remove at most one wall. I submit my code and only got `400 bad request`. I am a bit confused about this because I do not know it is the issue with my code or not. Below is my code, it may risk high time complexity:

```
public class Answer {   
    public static int answer(int[][] maze) { 

        // Your code goes here.
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[maze.length][maze[0].length];


        return dfs(0, 0, true, visited, maze, 1);

    } 
    private static int dfs(int x, int y, boolean allowRemove, boolean[][] visited, int[][] maze, int len){
         if(x == maze.length - 1 && y == maze[0].length - 1){

            return len;
        }

        int[] dx = {0, 0, -1, 1};
        int[] dy = {-1, 1, 0, 0};
        visited[x][y] = true;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
           int nx = dx[i] + x;
           int ny = dy[i] + y;
           if(nx < 0 || ny < 0 || nx >= maze.length || ny >= maze[0].length || visited[nx][ny]){
               continue;
           }
           if(maze[nx][ny] == 0){
               min = Math.min(dfs(nx, ny, allowRemove, visited, maze, len + 1), min);

           }else if(allowRemove){
                min = Math.min(dfs(nx, ny, false, visited, maze, len + 1),min);

           }
          if(min == maze.length + maze[0].length - 1){
              break;
          }
        }
        visited[x][y] = false;
        return min;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any way to solve this issue. I am keep getting time out expired. Any suggestion for optimization will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for asking, but how did you get the invite ?

Had one when everyone noticed it (when the impossible game came out), but didn't solved all the challenges in time, and I just get invitation expired.

And someone on stack overflow actually came into the same issue, altho don't know if figured it out : [Google foobar responds with Error(400)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420353/google-foobar-responds-with-error400?rq=1)